# Entities annotated with @Type(type = "jsonb") are discarded from jooq code generator

Tags: jooq, hibernate-types, jooq-codegen-maven

If i annotate an entity with @Type(type = "jsonb") from

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

**the entity is excluded** from the jOOQ code generation process (no table, records...).

Is there a solution that does not involve excluding the annotation? (https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/ ??! )

Thanks

Comment: The fact that the entity is excluded might be a bug. Mind reporting it here? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose. Ideally with some help reproducing it.

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder. I opened the ticket as you suggested https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10723.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the related [github issue #10723](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10723), this seems to be a limitation of how the [`JPADatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa/)  currently works (in jOOQ 3.13, 3.14). It uses Hibernate to create your schema in an in-memory H2 database prior to reverse engineering that.

H2 doesn't support the `JSONB` data type, although the `JSON` type is supported. This means that your `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType` cannot be used with this combination of features. You have a few options:

- Don't use the `JPADatabase`, which is always a source of limitations due to the above reasons. Using an actual PostgreSQL connection for jOOQ code generation will work better if you're planning on using vendor specific features. You could even run your code generation off a [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org) managed database, as is requested in [feature request #6551](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6551), or [shown in this example](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/main/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-testcontainers-example).
- Use the `JSON` type instead, which seems to work. This would be a pity, of course, as PostgreSQL offers better performance with `JSONB` than with `JSON`, but it might be a viable workaround in your case.